# SQL how to get OR statement in one record

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that returns more than one record because I am using an or

```
    SELECT m_o.ordernum, m_CD.fieldvalue
    FROM measurements.orders m_o
    INNER JOIN measurements.custom_data m_cd
    ON m_cd.ordernum = m_o.ordernum
    WHERE m_o.custnum = 'xxx'
    AND (m_cd.fieldname = 'primary_name' or m_cd.fieldname = 'secondary_name');
```

There is a way to get this returning one row but I am stumped.

Comment: add a `limit 1` or `top 1` depending on your sql engin

Comment: And without `ORDER BY` you will just pick random row with `top/limit 1`.

Comment: Sorry, I might have not explained it well enough.  I need both of those fieldvalues it returns, just would like them in one row, not two.  This would make it much easier to code later.

Comment: What sort of constraints ensure that you will have *only* two results for each (`ordernum`, `fieldvalue`) pair?  And can you rely on there *always* being two?

Comment: What database is used?

Comment: I can't rely on them having two ALWAYS.  I can rely on them only being two max.  Based on where this data comes from, there will always be a max of two.

Comment: The database is MySQL MyISAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the value associated with the primary name, if any, and the value associated with the secondary name, if any, in the same result rows, you  can join `measurements.custom_data` twice.  If you cannot rely on which one of those names has a value associated with it, then you must use outer joins.  For example:

```
SELECT
  m_o.ordernum,
  m_cd1.fieldvalue AS fieldValue1
  m_cd2.fieldvalue AS fieldValue2
FROM
  measurements.orders m_o
  LEFT JOIN measurements.custom_data m_cd1
    ON m_cd1.ordernum = m_o.ordernum AND m_cd1.fieldname = 'primary_name'
  LEFT JOIN measurements.custom_data m_cd2
    ON m_cd2.ordernum = m_o.ordernum AND m_cd2.fieldname = 'secondary_name'
WHERE
  m_o.custnum = 'xxx'
  AND (m_cd1.ordernum IS NOT NULL OR m_cd2.ordernum IS NOT NULL)
```

Note that the `fieldname` predicates are moved into the (outer) join conditions.  That directs which field value goes into which result column, and helps prevent duplicates.

Note also the `NOT NULL` conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  These prevent results being returned that have no value for *either* name.

Comment: Thanks John!  This is what I needed.  I rarely join tables on themselves but I knew what I needed was possible.  I am not able to up vote yet...

Comment: @echoBr00tal, I'm glad I could help.  If you are satisfied with my answer then you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark next to it, even though you do not have enough rep to upvote it.  Or if you prefer vkp's, then accept it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` and then aggregate on ordernum, as your fieldname will atmost have 2 values.

```
SELECT m_o.ordernum, 
max(case when m_cd.fieldname = 'primary_name' then m_CD.fieldvalue end) as col1,
max(case when m_cd.fieldname = 'secondary_name' then m_CD.fieldvalue end) as col2
FROM measurements.orders m_o
INNER JOIN measurements.custom_data m_cd
ON m_cd.ordernum = m_o.ordernum
WHERE m_o.custnum = 'xxx'
group by m_o.ordernum
```